# Get ID of Firebase Pushed Object Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase

Something very strange is happening whenever I try to get the ID of an item I pushed to my Firebase database... I used the code directly from [one of their examples](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html):

```
var fireBaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_ROOT);
var id = fireBaseRef.child("flintstones").push();
id.set({
    first: 'Fred',
    last: 'Flintstone'
}, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        //var name = id.key();
        console.log("Set with ID: " + id);
    }
});
```

When this code is run everything works as expected, the Forge portal shows the data was written properly to the database and I get the appropriate javascript console message:

```
"Set with ID: https://myfirebaseurl.com/flintstones/-JfjdUW4BT32DMgeuAdt"
```

The problem arises when I uncomment the line

```
var name = id.key();
```

As soon as I do that I get a javascript error indicating that no such method exists ("Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function."), I don't know what this is happening and I need to use the key value (in this case "-JfjdUW4BT32DMgeuAdt") elsewhere.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/namoqa/1/edit?js,console. Can you modify that jsbin so that it breaks?

Comment: Thank you so much for your very fast response. I copied and pasted your code into my own workspace and it still failed... then I saw the other answer from Rob DiMarco, once I changed the method to .name() it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you see will depend on which version of the client library you are using. Firebase Web / Node.js client libraries < 2.0.0 use `FirebaseRef.name()`, but that field was renamed in favor of `FirebaseRef.key()` for v2.0.0 and above. For more information, check out the changelog [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html).

Comment: This was the issue. Saving the changelog link for future reference, thanks!